# Can't do PHP Artisan Migrate with SQLSTATE [42000]

Tags: php, laravel, migration, laravel-8

I just want to PHP Artisan Migrate, I've just completed my table on migration but have error

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1067 Invalid default value for 'modified_date' 
(SQL: create table `dso` (`id` bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, 
`id_dso` bigint unsigned not null, `id_rso` bigint unsigned not null, 
`id_focus` bigint unsigned not null, `id_wilayah` bigint unsigned not null, `id_grup_wilayah` bigint unsigned not null, 
`nama_dso` varchar(255) not null, `created_by` varchar(255) not null, 
`created_date` timestamp not null, `modified_by` varchar(255) not null, 
`modified_date` timestamp not null, `status` tinyint(1) not null, 
`created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')
```

I've checked my completion that there is no error or any miss spelling

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('dso', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('id_dso')->constrained('dso_table_name');
            $table->foreignId('id_rso')->constrained('rso_table_name');
            $table->foreignId('id_focus')->constrained('focus_table_name');
            $table->foreignId('id_wilayah')->constrained('wilayah_table_name');
            $table->foreignId('id_grup_wilayah')->constrained('grup_wilayah_table_name');
            $table->string('nama_dso');
            $table->string('created_by');
            $table->timestamp('created_date',$precision = 0);
            $table->string('modified_by');
            $table->timestamp('modified_date',$precision = 0);
            $table->boolean('status');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('dso');
    }
}
```

I've not added nullable because all column have to fill
I'm using Laravel 8.6 and on Windows with XAMPP and MariaDB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `foreignId` method creates an UNSIGNED BIGINT equivalent column, so there is no need to use `unsignedBigInteger`. Just replace it.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('dso', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('id_dso');
        $table->foreignId('id_rso');
        $table->foreignId('id_focus');
        $table->foreignId('id_wilayah');
        $table->foreignId('id_grup_wilayah');
        $table->string('nama_dso');
        $table->string('created_by');
        $table->timestamp('created_date', $precision = 0);
        $table->string('modified_by');
        $table->timestamp('modified_date', $precision = 0);
        $table->boolean('status');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('dso');
}
```

EDIT: If your table name does not match Laravel's conventions, you may specify the table name by passing it as an argument to the constrained method:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('dso', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('id_dso')->constrained('dso_table_name');
        $table->foreignId('id_rso')->constrained('rso_table_name');
        $table->foreignId('id_focus')->constrained('focus_table_name');
        $table->foreignId('id_wilayah')->constrained('wilayah_table_name');
        $table->foreignId('id_grup_wilayah')->constrained('grup_wilayah_table_name');
        $table->string('nama_dso');
        $table->string('created_by');
        $table->timestamp('created_date', $precision = 0);
        $table->string('modified_by');
        $table->timestamp('modified_date', $precision = 0);
        $table->boolean('status');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('dso');
}
```

Comment: hi, there is no twice for `id_dso`,

Comment: Is `id_dso' and 'id_rso'

Comment: Yes, sorry, my bad. I've edited my answer

Comment: could me use `$table->timestamp('modified_date',0);` ?  I need for precision time

Comment: sure, it's documented in https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#column-method-timestamp

Comment: Please note that I've edited my answer for using the constrained method in case you don't use Laravel's conventions table names

Comment: is still same error  `  1   D:\XAMPP\htdocs\laravel_sales\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:485
      PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1067 Invalid default value for 'modified_date'")

  2   D:\XAMPP\htdocs\laravel_sales\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:485
      PDOStatement::execute() `

Comment: That's not the same error. Now you face a default value error for modified_date column. Verify that table was not created before running the migration again.

Comment: I'm using constrained method , but still error message
`  1   D:\XAMPP\htdocs\laravel_sales\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:485
      PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1067 Invalid default value for 'modified_date'")  `

Comment: there is no table dso, because this is new project

Comment: Sometimes despite migration failure, the tables are created. That's why you have to double-check. The constrained method seems to be working now, but the problem is in timestamps.
Try adding ->nullable()->default(null) to modified_date column definition

Comment: Did you mean like this ` $table->timestamp('modified_date',$precision = 0)->nullable()->default(null); `

Comment: There is something strange. While d `php artisan migrate` there is an error but, suddenly the table is in MariaDb, why is this happening?

Comment: It's a common behavior when developing your migrations. You can use php artisan migrate:fresh while testing your migrations. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#roll-back-migrate-using-a-single-command

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you have used [`timestamps()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#column-method-timestamps) instead of [`timestamp()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#column-method-timestamp).

So, your migration should be like this:

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('dso', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('id_dso')->unique();
        $table->id('id_rso');
        $table->id('id_focus');
        $table->id('id_wilayah');
        $table->id('id_grup_wilayah');
        $table->string('nama_dso');
        $table->string('created_by');
        $table->timestamp('created_date');
        $table->string('modified_by');
        $table->timestamp('modified_date');
        $table->boolean('status');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Check the available methods in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#available-column-types).

Comment: why I can't used " $precision = 0" ? because is need for every updated will record on database
And why 'id_dso' must be foreignId?

Comment: You can use that, it id already the default, no need to write it again, my code works, check it out...

Comment: I was update my error, can you please re-check my post.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that the problem is that you are declaring twice the same column.
`$table->foreignId('id_dso');` creates an unsigned bit integer.
After that you use again `$table->unsignedBigInteger('id_rso');` which does the same thing.

Comment: could you help me to write new code, please?

Comment: Please note that column names are different: id_rso and id_dso